# I cant save my highchart chart data in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I cant save data in localstorage, I get the result [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Here is the code

```
var usersonline = null;
var maxonline = 50;
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
 chart: {
     events: {
         load: function () {

             // set up the updating of the chart each second
             var series = this.series[0];
             setInterval(function () {
                 var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                     y = Math.round(usersonline);
                 series.addPoint([x, y], true, false);
             }, 1000);
         }
     }
 },

 time: {
     useUTC: false
 },

 rangeSelector: {
     buttons: [{
         count: 1,
         type: 'hour',
         text: '1H'
     }, {
         count: 3,
         type: 'hour',
         text: '3H'
     }, {
         type: 'all',
         text: 'All'
     }],
     inputEnabled: false,
     selected: 2
 },

 title: {
     text: 'Live Chart of Players Online'
 },

 exporting: {
     enabled: false
 },
 yAxis: {
      title: 'Players Online',
      min: 0,
      plotLines: [{
         color: 'red', // Color value
         label: {
                 text: "Max Player Line"
         },
         value: maxonline, // Value of where the line will appear
         width: 2 // Width of the line    
         }]
 },
 series: [{
     name: 'Players Online',
     connectNulls: false,
     data: (function () {
         var data = [],
             time = (new Date()).getTime(),
             i;
         if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
             if (localStorage.getItem("chartdata") === null) {
                 localStorage.setItem('chartdata',[])
                 data = []
                 console.log("No Data Found, Creating Some!")
             } else {
                 data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('chartdata'))
                 console.log("Chart Data Loaded.")
             }
         } else {
             console.log("localStorage is not Supported. Saving Chart Data will not work.")
         }
         // generate an array of random data
         window.onbeforeunload = function(){
             console.log("Chart data Saved")
             localStorage.chartdata = JSON.stringify(data)
         }
         return data;
     }())
 }],
 lang: {
     noData: "No Data."
 },
 noData: {
     style: {
         fontWeight: 'bold',
         fontSize: '40px',
         color: '#303030'
     }
 }
});
```

If I refresh the page it shows the chart as blank and It doesnt display "No Data" so there is data there but it is broken. What I want to happen is When I refresh the page it will keep the data, even when the browser or computer gets restarted.

Is there any solution to this problem, I tried multiple ways but none of them work.

This is a live data chart that I need to save data so The Chart doesnt go blank if you accidently refresh the page.

Comment: Hi @Welcome_234, Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uytxdoqv/ everything seems to work as expected. Could you adapt the example to show the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So the reason why when you get the item it says `[Object object]` is because `localStorage.setItem` accepts a `DOMString`, not an object. `setItem` will use `toString` to coerce values into a string, and  `Object.prototype.toString` will always be `[object Object]`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

You need to use `JSON.stringify` to convert your array into a valid JSON string in your `localStorage.setItem` function call and then use `JSON.parse` to parse that string when you use `localStorage.getItem`.

```
const loki = { "type": "dog", "name": "Loki" }

// Sets [object Object] in local storage
localStorage.setItem("lokiKey", loki)

// Sets "{"type":"dog","name":"Loki"}" in local storage
localStorage.setItem("lokiKey", JSON.stringify(loki))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use myChart.addSeries ? If Series have been changed you should calling method redraw

Comment: Hello! Please make sure that your answer is relevant to the question that is being asked. In specific, the question is related to saving data in local storage, not redrawing the chart.

Comment: Who says that problem is related to local storage? Hi has some data in storage. Code presented looks like have an issue with dynamic populating data. So my vision is that chart can’t fill series from data that already stored in storage